# Why '401: unauthorized' when configuring ssrs in integration mode?

Tags: reporting-services, error, integration, wss-3.0

I'm trying to setup SSRS in integration mode, but when I attempt to navigate to 'reporting services' -> 'set server defaults' in sharepoint central administration I get the following error:

> An unexpected error occurred while
>   connecting to the report server.
>   Verify that the report server is
>   available and configured for
>   SharePoint integrated mode. --> Server
>   was unable to process request. --->
>   The request failed with HTTP status
>   401: Unauthorized.

SSRS and the sharepoint front end are located on different boxes.

Any steps to troubleshoot what's going wrong?

**Edit: A bit more detail**

I can connect to the report server on the local machine by manually typing on the url `http://<server>/reportserver`; I just can't access it through sharepoint. Also, the ssrs config wizard indicates that sharepoint integration is successfully configured (via the green checkbox).

Comment: Did you go into "Grant Database access" in Central Admin first?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the SSRS Config wizard you'll find links to the reporting services web service - these can be copied & pasted into a browser window to test for connectivity.

I've found that the Event Log can be helpful to find out what's causing the problems, usually SQL or IIS will throw a more detailed error here which may help.

Comment: see edit for a little more detail. Also, unfortunately, the event logs on both machines don't seem to be logging any relevant errors.

Comment: What was the result from the "Grant Database Access" screen in Central Administration?

Comment: It just brought me back the the central admin screen without error.

Comment: The application management screen that is.

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup Kerberos? It sounds like you might not have Kerberos setup correctly (Kerberos is probably required if you want to pass through user credentials from SharePoint through to SSRS).

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283324.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326356.aspx
- https://web.archive.org/web/20160228171347/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/martinkearn/archive/2007/04/23/configuring-kerberos-for-sharepoint-2007-part-1-base-configuration-for-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was doing the same thing and got the error, so for me predominantly it was an SPN issue which is basically if you use kerberose authentication and do a double hop from one server to another it fails throwing 401. Now the Solution/workaround for this is you can log in directly to the Database Server and try accessing the Central Admin from there. It shows you all the options and pages. This is working because technically there is no hops on the servers now and it is directly accessing the back end.

Hope this Helps.