# Why won't SSRS get an image from SharePoint?

Tags: permissions, reporting-services

For the first time I have an SSRS report with an external image that resides on SharePoint. We are running SSRS under NetworkService.

When I preview the report from Visual Studio, the report successfully shows the SharePoint-hosted image.

When I run the report in my browser from http:///reports, I get a 401 response from SharePoint.

Permissions for the SharePoint library include read-access for 'Everyone'.

Do you know why I get the 401?

Comment: Wish I had something useful to add. Brings back nostalgia. Haven't thought of SQL Server Reporting Services in years. You don't mention versions. Maybe something in this area of the docs on supported versions of SQL and SharePoint might help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/supported-combinations-of-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-server?view=sql-server-2016&preserve-view=true

Comment: Also, the answers in this somewhat related thread might point you in the right direction if you've got nothing else to go on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/why-401-unauthorized-when-configuring-ssrs-in-integration-mode?rq=1

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be that to retrieve an external image you need to specify an SSRS Unattended Execution Account.

So the solution is not SharePoint specific - it's only that SharePoint was hosting the external images. The answer is SSRS configuration.

Thanks.